Iterate through subfolders and open a folder in Explorer when a string match is made using Excel VBA
I am attempting to open a folder with explorer.exe triggered by a single click on a cell when there is a value in the clicked cell.
I have the click action and the open folder action working fine as I have used them in other subs.
Where I am failing is in being able to find the correct subfolder based only on the value in the cell being clicked.
This code will start the sub with the single click:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 'single click version

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String
    
    If Len(ActiveCell) > 3 Then
    
        If Intersect(Target, Range("ay5:ay15")) Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
        
            wO = ActiveCell
            
            DropboxLocation 'gets users Dropbox folder path and sets it to variable userDBfolder
        
            HostFolder = userDBfolder & "\~ Completed Jobs\Jobsite Pictures\"
        
            Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            DoFolder FileSystem.getFolder(HostFolder)
            
        End If
    Else
    End If
        
End Sub

The following code will print all the folder paths to the Immediate Window:
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    
    Dim subFolder
    Dim pathMatch

    For Each subFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder subFolder
        Debug.Print (subFolder) 'This is where I also put the search code found below
    Next
    
End Sub

What I am trying to do with the result is to find a specific string in the folder path and then open the folder.  My code for this is:
        pathMatch = InStr(subFolder, wO)
        If pathMatch > 0 Then
            Shell "explorer.exe" & subFolder
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If

and it doesn't work. The folder is never found.  I am thinking this is because of a type mismatch with the current subFolder being an object and wO being a string. I was thinking to convert the current iteration of subFolder to a string but I couldn't find a simple explanation for doing that.
While Debug.Print can coerce the subFolder value into the Immediate Window, I don't think inStr or the Shell command can use the subFolder in it's current type.
Any thoughts on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Maybe test against subFolder.Name instead?  And use subFolder.Path when using Shell.

Also, I think there should be a space between the program name and the subfolder path in your Shell function (ie Shell "explorer.exe " & subFolder.Path).

@TimWilliams @Domenic - subFolder.Name took care of the pathMatch problem.  It does find the folder but Shell "explorer.exe" & subFolder.Path comes back as File not found.

Try this out - some changes in the folder enumeration:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 'single click version

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String, v, foundFolder As Object
    
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("ay5:ay15")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    v = Trim(Target.Value)
    If Len(v) <= 3 Then Exit Sub 'value too short
        
    DropboxLocation 'ideally this would be a Function...
    HostFolder = userDBfolder & "\~ Completed Jobs\Jobsite Pictures\"

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set foundFolder = FindFolder(FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder), CStr(v))
    If Not foundFolder Is Nothing Then
        'space, and quotes around path
        Shell "explorer.exe """ & foundFolder.Path & """", vbNormalFocus 
    Else
        MsgBox "No folder found for '" & v & "'"
    End If
    
        
End Sub

'Find a folder whose name contains `strMatch`, starting with `fldrStart`
'  Returns Nothing if no match
Function FindFolder(fldrStart As Object, strMatch As String)
    Dim queue As New Collection
    Dim subFolder As Object, fldr As Object
    
    queue.Add fldrStart
    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set fldr = queue(1)   'grab item from queue
        queue.Remove 1        '...and remove it
        If InStr(1, fldr.Name, strMatch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set FindFolder = fldr
            Exit Function
        End If
        'add subfolders to queue
        For Each subFolder In fldr.subFolders
            queue.Add subFolder
        Next subFolder
    Loop
End Function


I tried this and when it gets to this line Set foundFolder = FindFolder(FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder), CStr(v)) it returns Path not Found.

Sorry I had the call to DropboxLocation  commented out....

I just noticed that too.

I still couldn't get this to work and have been working tracking down the issue with your code Tim.  I changed Shell "explorer.exe """ & foundFolder.Path & """", to Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & foundFolder, vbNormalFocus, and it works fantastic.  Thank you so very much Tim.  If you want to make that change in your answer, I will accept it as the answer.

I added the vbNormalFocus above.  I left the quotes around the path though  - seems like it's safer in case your path has spaces.
